# Full height div not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

I am using the code below to try and set my div height so they are all equal dependant on the tallest div given. However my boxes are still displaying as the below image - I have done an alert and that is firing so I know my jQuery is working:

**Issue:**

[image]
**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max = -1;
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph > div').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height(); 
    max = h > max ? h : max;

    $(this).css({'min-height': max});
  });
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph">
    <p><span class="menu1Title"></span></p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menuBoxesParagraph{
    width: 25%;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    margin: 2% 1% 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph:before, .menuBoxesParagraph:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.menuBoxesParagraph:after { clear: both; }
.menuBoxesParagraph { zoom: 1; }
```

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan will do

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan http://jsfiddle.net/36e1ub3x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solves your issue(JS):

```
    var max = -1;
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {

    var h = $(this).height(); 
    max = h > max ? h : max;

  });


$(".menuBoxesParagraph").css("height",max+"px");
```

Two things i guess, one was you were using a div in a selector `menuBoxesParagraph > div` which was non existent.
Because of that max was -1 always.
Also height was missing "px" values.

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/36e1ub3x/14/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/36e1ub3x/11/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var highestBox = 0;
  $('.menuBoxesParagraph').each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() > highestBox) highestBox = $(this).height();
  });
  $('.menuBoxesParagraph').height(highestBox);
});
```

```css
#nonTabbed {
    width:980px;
    diplay:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 50px 0;
}
.menu1 {
    float:left;
    width:31%;
    margin:0 2% 0 0;
}
.menu1Title {
    color:#F70000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu1Title2 {
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph {
    width: 25%;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    margin: 2% 1% 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph:before, .menuBoxesParagraph:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph:after {
    clear: both;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nonTabbed">
  <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph">
    <p><span class="menu1Title">Mains </span>
    </p>
    <p>Roast leg of pork with crackling, gravy and applesauce</p>
    <p>Stuffed loin of pork with sage and onion forcemeat with calvados gravy.</p>
    <p>Chicken supreme roasted with lemon, olives and wild oregano with a hint of white wine.</p>
    <p>Free range chicken breasts marinated in orange and ginger.</p>
    <p>Butterflied leg of lamb stuffed with couscous, apricots, almonds, dates, preserved lemons and rubbed with sumac. Accompanied with minted yoghurt.</p>
    <p>Roast rump of lamb rubbed with rosemary, garlic and olive oil served with a salsa Verdi.</p>
    <p>Roast rib of beef with Yorkshire puddings, gravy and horseradish (excess $2.50 per person)</p>
    <p>Whole fillet of beef marinated in port, bay leaves and thyme served with a béarnaise sauce (excess of $5.00 per person)</p>
    <p>Hot smoked salmon fillets, smoked over our own spices and woodchips served with lemon mayo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph">
    <p><span class="menu1Title">Sides</span>
    </p>
    <p><span class="menu1Title2">Hot</span>
    </p>
    <p>Baby new potatoes drizzled with extra virgin olive oil and dill.</p>p>Roasted potatoes cooked whole garlic cloves and thyme.</p>
    <p>Dauphoise potatoes, sliced potatoes baked with cream, garlic and nutmeg</p>
    <p>Hasselback potatoes, whole potatoes sliced ¾ way down and topped with parmesan and baked till crisp.</p>
    <p>Roast seasonal vegetables with herbs.</p>
    <p>Creamed spinach with nutmeg.</p>
    <p>Pumpkin mash.</p>
    <p><span class="menu1Title2">Cold</span>
    </p>
    <p>Fennel, orange and toasted almond salad.</p>
    <p>Baby roasted potato salad drizzled with balsamic dressing and shaved parmesan.</p>
    <p>Tagliatelle with roasted vine tomatoes, black olives and green peppers tossed in basil dressing.</p>
    <p>Moroccan couscous salad with baked egg plant, dates, pistachio nuts and preserved lemon.</p>
    <p>Honey roasted kumara, chickpeas, coriander, spinach and tamarind dressing.</p>
    <p>Baby gem lettuce with roasted pear, toasted walnuts and blue cheese dressing.</p>
    <p>Rocket, watercress, broccoli, French beans, peas, fresh herbs and feta cheese salad.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph">
    <p><span class="menu1Title">Desserts</span>
    </p>
    <p>Lemon soufflé <span class="gf">GF</span>
    </p>
    <p>Hazelnut meringue stack with whipped cream and berries. <span class="gf">GF</span>
    </p>
    <p>Ginger sticky toffee pudding with toffee sauce and anglaise</p>
    <p>Apple, apricot and nut strudel with our own home made ice cream</p>
    <p>Chocolate and almond torte <span class="gf">GF</span>
    </p>
    <p>Plum frangipan</p>
    <p>Baked chocolate cheese cake</p>
    <p>Banoffee pie- biscuit base filled with toffee caramel, banana, whipped cream and shave chocolate</p>
    <p>Pear poached in sweet wine with cinnamon and star anise, served with cinnamon Chantilly cream and shortbread fingers</p>
    <p>Brown sugar meringues with fresh fruit salad <span class="gf">GF</span> 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isnt need to use a loop the second time to set the height i think!

Comment: @varun you are right that,  `$('.menuBoxesParagraph').height(highestBox)` is easy to write. But that is also the same internal operation as the one I use.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following JQUERY:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var max = -1;
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph > div').ready(function() {
        var h = $(this).height(); 
        max = h > max ? h : max;
        alert(h+"--"+max);    
        //$(this).css({'min-height': max});
        $(".menuBoxesParagraph").css("height",max+"px");
    });
});
```